# populate combobox with values from column from two dimensional array

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a two dimensional array.
Like for example :

`viewScope.myTest = [];
viewScope.myTest.push(["row1col1", "row1col2", "row1col3"]);
viewScope.myTest.push(["row2col1", "row2col2", "row2col3"]);`

etc

In my combobox I would like to show all the values of column3.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through all 3rd Columns of the array, you would need to do something like this:

```
// Creating the Structure you already got
var viewScope = {
    myTest: []
}
viewScope.myTest.push(["row1col1", "row1col2", "row1col3"]);
viewScope.myTest.push(["row2col1", "row2col2", "row2col3"]);
viewScope.myTest.push(["row3col1", "row3col2", "row3col3"]);

// Get the Combobox by ID
var myCombobox = document.getElementById("myCombo");

// Iterate through all options of myTest
for (var i in viewScope.myTest)
{ 
    // Create a new Option for the Select
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    // Add the 3rd Columns as Text
    option.text = viewScope.myTest[i][2];
    // Add the Option to the Select
    myCombobox.add(option);
}
```

Why?! - you are creating a 2 Dimensional Array. it works like: Array[row][col] from your example.
Because those are indexes, they start with 0 and count up to length-1.

Please take a look at: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/fjo20ccw/)

Comment: My problem is that I'm getting the data from somwhere else. That's why I used a viewScope. When I replace myTest with viewScope.myTest I'm getting an error : [ReferenceError] 'console' not found

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what you say, you don't have a 2-dim array. It's a 1-dim array that contains 2 1-dim arrays. To get only the values for column 3, you have to create a new array:

```
var col3values= [];
for(var i in viewScope.myTest)
    if(viewScope.myTest[i].length>=3)
        col3values.push(viewScope.myTest[i][2];
```